# LTI system's response to input's integral

Tags: dynamical-systems

Suppose that $H$ is a linear time invariant system. If the response of $H$ to the input $u$ is $y$, then what is its response to integral of $u$?

Answer (score 0):

Since $H$ is an LTI system, it has an impulse-response, say $h(t)$ and for $u(t)$ as the input signal:
$$y(t)=h(t)*u(t)$$
where $*$ represents the convolution. Note that the above equation is the *inherent* property of LTI systems. Now since the integral and convolution are both linear operators, if $u_I=\int u$ then
$$\begin{align}y_I(t)&=h(t)*u_I(t)\\
&=h(t)*\int_{t_0}^t u(\tau)d\tau\\
&=\int_{t_0}^t h(\tau)*u(\tau)d\tau=\int_{t_0}^t y(\tau)d\tau
\end{align}$$
Or in other words $y_I=\int y$

Comment: I need an explanation on why $h(t)*\int_{t_0}^t u(\tau ) d\tau$ equals $\int_{t_0}^t  h(t)*u(\tau ) d\tau$

Comment: @JohnRailman As I said, both operators are _linear_. So they are interchangeable (they are both integrals and integrals can switch places). And as a side-note, I am just curious that why haven't you accepted any answer for your questions? Not saying that's a big deal, but for some people it is considered as a token of appreciation for their time.